# Cannot have multiple monitor modes in new Kali 2.0

Tags: kali-linux

In previous versions of Kali Linux, we could have **mon0 mon1 ...** on the same wireless card **(wlan0)**. But in Kali 2.0 which says have an updated **aircrack-ng** tool and new way of having monitor interfaces like **wlan0mon**. Now the problem is what if i want another **monitor mode** on same wireless card. I googled checked out the forums where someone posted similar question but no help. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to do it. I thought Kali Linux 2.0 is really good but after that I'm thinking it's a big fail. Change from wlan0 to wlan0mon is killer. Why? Many scripts will work on all version except 2.0 in Kali because wlan0mon. It's really sad and If we can't do more monmitors mode, I'm thinking, I will leave this distribution for some time.

EDIT: Some person said me kernel 2.6.31 or higher use virtual layer or something like that. Try to use help of command "iw" and u will see that it's might possible to add new monitors mode :)

Answer (score 0):

indeed as anon said, now you need to use the "*iw*" command to create multiple monitors, it seems like "*iw wlan0mon interface add monX type monitor*" does the job, however at the moment there are some flaws to it, or it's just me being incompetent with the "*iw*". for eg. mon0 is inoperable when mon1,2,3... are working perfectly fine and i can't turn power saving off for monitors >0. other than that.. works fine